# Rabbitmq listen to UDP connection

Tags: message-queue, rabbitmq

Is there a way to have RabbitMQ listen for UDP connections and put those packets into somesort of default queue which can then be pulled from by a standard client?  Would ActiveMQ or ZeroMQ be better for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using a simple proxy front for receiving incoming UDP packets and sending them off to RabbitMQ via AMQP. E.g. in Python you can setup a UDP server and then use the AMQP Pika library to speak with your RabbitMQ server.

Cheers!

Comment: This is what i ended up doing and its worked out nicely Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Someone also built a udp-exchange plugin for rabbitMQ.
I haven't personally used this, but it seems like it would do the job for you without having to write your own udp to amqp forwarder ..

https://github.com/tonyg/udp-exchange

here's the excerpt

> Extends RabbitMQ Server with support for a new experimental exchange type, x-udp. 
>   Each created x-udp exchange listens on a specified UDP port for incoming messages, and relays them on to the queues bound to the exchange. It also takes messages published to the exchange and relays them on to a specified IP address and UDP port.